# Creating log file excerpts with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

We have a list of log files, one for a day, named `app_2020-04-11.log`, `app_2020-04-12.log` etc. Now we want to get excerpts of these files, retrieving some lines of the original files, and store these lines in different files, one for each log file: `logex_2020-04-11.log`, `logex_2020-04-12.log` etc.

I can't find a solution how to output the search results in different files. I thought that the `OutFile`-command could help me but I don't know how to set the Out-File Path correct with a variable.

```
Get-ChildItem app*.log |
Select-String -Pattern "findme here" |
Out-File -FilePath {$_.name -replace 'app','logex'}
```

How can I modify the out file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command should help you out.
We iterate over all `app*.log` files, then we iterate over each line. If the line contains the pattern of interest (in this example `find me here`), then we append that line to the renamed file:

```
Get-ChildItem app*.log | 
ForEach-Object { 
  foreach($line in Get-Content $_.Name) { 
    if ($line -match "findme here"){
      Add-Content -Path ($_.Name -replace "app", "logex") -Value $line
    }
  }
}
```